# Safe way to share variables between UI form and background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables, thread-safety

In my project I have a windows forms application where I want show the user the status of the background work using some variables from the background thread. Depending on their value I show some information or other. How could I face the problem of sharing variables between threads in a safe way?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Any effort?

Comment: No. I just wanted to know where to start as I have suffered for Invalid Access Exceptions in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net already comes with a [System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class specifically to handle performing background tasks and communicating with a GUI. Use it.

---

**Update**

If you want another approach , this is what I do.

1) Create you "message" classes. This stores all the information you want to share.

2) Create a Queue for each thread. Use a SyncLock (C# lock) to read/write to it.

3) When you want to talk to a thread, send it a message object with a copy of all the information it needs by adding the message to the queue.

4) The worker thread can then read from the queue, reading and processing each message in order. When there are no messages, simply sleep.

Make sure that you don't share objects between the two threads. Once your GUI thread sticks a message in the Queue, the GUI thread no longer owns the message. It cannot hold a reference to the message, or you will get yourself into trouble.

This won't give you the best possible performance, but it will be good enough for most applications. And more importantly, it will make it much harder to make a mistake.